# Inserting a Plain Text Content Control with a Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to automate the generation of a pre-existing and original .docx form using a macro and need to insert plain text Content Controls into the form in various locations via the macro. On the original .docx form, the Content Control fields are 8 underlined spaces and are surrounded by parentheses. In the original form, when I click on the Content Controls, I only need to click once, and when I click on it and input information, the underlined spaces disappear and I'm left with only the text that I've entered and the parentheses. How do you make a Content Control that has these properties with VBA? In my macro-generated document, I have to click first in the Content Control on the underlined spaces and then on the 3 dots to the left in order to enter the data. However, when I do this in the macro generated document, the underlines stay. If I click once on the Content Control in the macro generated document, the input is added to the spaces instead of replacing them. Also, how do you underline the spaces in the Content Control such that the underline is present before the Content Control is clicked on but disappears when the text is entered? The parentheses should not be underlined at any point.

I tried the below code. I spent about 2 hours googling stuff to try to find a solution and was unsuccessful. I also tried doing it with objects, but I lost that code and can't seem to find it. That object code that I found didn't work either.

```
Private Sub POAContentControl()
    
    With Selection
        .TypeText Text:="("
        .Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlText)
        .TypeText Text:="        "
        .Font.UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .EndKey unit:=wdLine 'Exits the Content Control
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        .TypeText Text:=")"
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with the text inside the original content control is almost certainly not 8 underlined spaces. If it was the underline would not disappear. Instead it will simply be 8 underscores.

The reason that you can't overtype what is in the content control is that you haven't set the placeholder text. Instead your code simply types into the content control.

The code below should get you started:

```
Private Sub POAContentControl()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    With rng
        .Text = "()"
        .MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        Dim cc As ContentControl
        Set cc = .ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText, rng)
        cc.SetPlaceholderText Text:="________"
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT:

To get underlined spaces you can either modify the Placeholder Text style to have an underline, which will affect all content controls, or apply the underline to the specific control after you have set the placeholder text.

```
Private Sub POAContentControl()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    With rng
        .Text = "()"
        .MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        With .ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText, rng)
            .SetPlaceholderText Text:="      "
            .Range.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This code gets the content control very close to what it should be. The size is just a bit off. If I remove an underscore, it's too short and if I keep it, it's a tiny bit too big. When I turn on show paragraph marks & other symbols in the original doc, it does show dots that are underlined so I'm pretty sure that those are spaces that are somehow underlined. Is there a way to do this using spaces that are underlined? The underlines need to disappear when data is input.

If not, Is there a way to change the font size of the underscore in the object? I've tried but haven't figured out how.

Comment: See also John Korchook's page about adding CCs on the Mac with vba. http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/content-controls-for-macos-cool-code/

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thank you Timothy. One additional question: When using your code, the underline is a little bit fainter in the content control then it is when the macro is generating normal underlined text (i.e. underlined text that is not in a content control). Is there some way to make it an identical underline? On the original .docx that I'm trying to mirror, the underlines that have the content control look identical to the underlines that are not in a content control. I've tried a lot of variations of the underline but haven't been able to get it exactly the same as the original. Thanks!

Comment: @Stomper - the formatting of a content control showing placeholder text is controlled by the style Placeholder Text. By default this is a light grey.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Is there a simple way to create the style in VBA so that it changes just the color of the underline? That's the only thing I need to change in the content control part. When I create a style currently, it also changes the paragraph formatting, which I don't want it to. Additionally, it changes the width of the content control and I can't figure out why; the text size and font are unchanged. Many thanks!

Comment: @Stomper - Placeholder Text is a built-in style. Why don't you take a look at its properties and then you will see what you can do.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - I've spent the better part of a day on this and I can't seem to get the underlines the thickness that I want. I've tried editing the Placeholder Text style and also adding the below code before the code you provided above but couldn't achieve the desired result. I admit I don't have much experience working with styles. 
``` 
Dim ObjStyle As Style Set ObjStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text")
ObjStyle.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle 
ObjStyle.Font.UnderlineColor = wdColorBlack 
``` 
Do you have any further suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @Stomper - go back to the original document you are attempting to replicate and examine it more carefully.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I went back to the original document as you suggested and looked at the font window that is opened when I right-click on the underlined content control fields and select 'Font'. It is identical in the original document to the macro generated document, but the thickness of the underlines still does not match for the content control fields. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: @Stomper - you need to look at *all* of the properties of the text. Use Shift+F1 to display the Reveal Formatting pane. See also http://addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm